# How many vectors of Hamming weight L in "random" K dimensional subspace of F_2^N ? Or how good/bad is random linear block code ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coding-theory, it.information-theory

Consider linear $N$-dimensional space $F_2^N$.
Consider its $K$ dimensional subspace $V \subset F_2^N$.
Let us calculate $w(k,V,N)$ number of vectors in $V$ of Hamming weight $k$ in $V$.

Since there is finite number of subspaces we can calculate average:
$\sum_{V} w(k,V,N)$.

**Question** is there something known about it ?

---

Coding theory motivation - is to understand how good/bad is a random linear code ?
I.e. error-correcting code is precisely $V$ in $F_2^N$.
Code is bad if we have many vectors of small Hamming weight.

---

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the average very explicitly. For $v\in F_2^N$, let $||v||$ denote the Hamming weight of $v$. Changing the order of summation, your sum can be re-written as
  $$ \sum_{v\colon\ ||v||=k} T(v), $$ 
where $T(v)$ is the number of $K$-dimensional subspaces of $F_2^N$, containing $v$. Now, if $k>0$, then $v\ne 0$, and the number of subspaces in question does not depend on $v$ and is equal to the number of $(K-1)$-dimensional subspaces of $F_2^{N-1}$, which is 
  $$ \frac{(2^{N-1}-1)(2^{N-1}-2))(2^{N-1}-4)\cdots(2^{N-1}-2^{K-2})}{(2^{K-1}-1)(2^{K-1}-2)(2^{K-1}-4)\cdots(2^{K-1}-2^{K-2})}. $$
The sum under consideration is therefore equal to the product of this fraction and the binomial coefficient $\binom Nk$ (the number of vectors $v$ of weight $k$), and the average is obtained by dividing this sum by the total number of all $K$-dimensional subspaces of $F_2^N$, which is 
  $$ \frac{(2^N-1)(2^N-2)(2^N-4)\cdots(2^N-2^{K-1})}{(2^K-1)(2^K-2)(2^K-4)\cdots(2^K-2^{K-1})}.  $$
After cancellations, the average is equal to
  $$ \frac{2^K-1}{2^N-1}\,\binom Nk = 2^{K-N}\binom Nk \, (1+o(1)),\ K\to\infty. $$

Comment: @Seva WOW !!! Can we understand what distribution we get when K,N are "large" ?  It might be just something simple related to binomial distribution tending to normal distribution ... 

Comment: I appended two lines to my answer to address this.

Comment: if sum k=1...N I expect to get 1+O(1), but we get 2^K... is it correct ? 

Comment: What we computed is the average (=expected) number of vectors of weight $k$ in a randomly chosen $K$-dimensional subspace. Summing over $k$, we get the total number of vectors in a random $K$-dimensional subspace, which is $2^K$. Makes sense?

Comment: One more comment to interpret the result. We have shown that the proportion of vectors of weight $k$ among all vectors of a random $K$-dimensional subset is about $2^{-N}\binom Nk$, which is the proportion of vectors of weight $k$ among all vectors of $F_2^K$. In other words, lying in a $K$-dimensional subspace is independent from having weight $k$. Pretty expectable!

Comment: To comment just above --- if "K" is very big  e.g. extreme case K=N - so there is only one "subspace" which is space itself, then of course number of weight "k" vectors is C_n^k, so if "K" is something near it we may expect similar result...  